# How do I transfer my PS+ to another PSN account?

Tags: ps4, psn

I have one account that I have bought a ton of stuff on, but I cannot access it as I must have randomized the date of birth. I have tried many ways to access by trying all types of passwords I would use, and the date of birth of almost everyone in my family but it still won't work.

I think my only choice is to transfer the PS+ another PSN account, because I know everything will be on the PS4.

Does anyone know of a way to move it?

Answer (score 3):

[You can't transfer your plus to another account.](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/Games-Services/Can-i-transfer-my-plus-to-another-account/td-p/42805071)

Sorry, good luck. Try contacting PlayStation's customer support, they might be able to recover your account (I'm speculating here) if you can provide bank details or what ever you may have used to purchase stuff from the other account, it MAY be enough for them to help you out, don't quote me on that though.